# how to eliminate any number after the floating point?

Tags: java, floating-point, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision

Is there any function returns only the real number without the floating point? For an example,
`func(1.xxx)->1`
`func(52.xx)->52`
`func(0.xx)->0`

Is there any function does so?

Comment: Typecast it into Integer then you will get the decimal value..

Comment: have you try Math.round() ?

Comment: `int a = (int) doble_value;` Just cast it to Integer.

Comment: @Haresh actually not I searched google but the results were not what ia m searching for

Comment: @Elpharaoh - what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: @user3145373ツ i want only the real/integer number to be returned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply casting to int would truncate everything past the decimal point.

```
float f1 = 10.345;
int i1 = (int) f1; // Gives 10

float f2 = 10.897;
int i2 = (int) f2; // Also gives 10
```

Comment: Cast to floor, `Math#round()` to... well... round.

Comment: would you mind up-voting my question please

Comment: @Rogue That's correct for positive numbers. Negative numbers work a little differently. We are talking about truncating here. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344815/how-do-the-floor-and-ceiling-functions-work-on-negative-numbers

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
double d = 100.675;

System.out.println((int) d);
```

this gives you `100`.

```
System.out.println(Math.round(d));
```

gives you `101`.

You can also use :

```
new java.text.DecimalFormat("#").format(10.0); // => "10"
```

now the choice is yours that how you want to do and main thing depend on that what is your expected output is.

Comment: Thank you,, you answer ofcourse correct as well.

Comment: Yes I know, I have posted this first in comment then answers came of above.